# Como considerar um tempo de resposta ideal para endpoints em uma API Restful?

Tags: api, web-service, restful

##### Como devo considerar que o tempo de resposta de um endpoint da minha API Restful é bom ou ruim?

Sei que o tempo de resposta de um endpoint depende de vários fatores, do ambiente onde ele está rodando, do que ele executa de fato, se usa transações e faz inserts ou somente consultas, etc. Mas como devo considerar que meu endpoint possui um tempo de resposta ruim? Existe algo que eu deva levar em consideração ou alguma fórmula?

Algo que ouço com certa frequência nas empresas que já trabalhei é que um endpoint POST em prod numa aplicação escalável que demore mais de 1s já é ruim, mas eu particularmente acho superficial e não sei se devo avaliar dessa forma, embora eu realmente ache ruim que um endpoint demore por exemplo esses 1s para retornar. Não sei se devo usar isso como base para considerar bom/ruim. Devo?

Comment: *"Existe algo que eu deva levar em consideração..."* Sim, os consumidores. Se eles reclamarem, então o tempo de resposta passa a ser relevante na qualidade da API. Qual o tempo de resposta? Isso ai varia de contexto, fica impossível determinar um valor.

Comment: Você quer definir métricas de performance universais? Se for, isso não existe. Por exemplo num eCommerce se demorar 1s por requisição em uma venda o cliente se incomoda e fica achando que tem algum problema com o site ou põe em cheque a credibilidade do site. Agora esses mesmos 1s de resposta em uma aplicação de Analise Tomográfica iria chamar a atenção de médicos do mundo inteiro, talvez todos os diversos especialistas em tomografia migrassem para a sua aplicação.

Comment: Não existe um padrão, cada caso é um caso. Também é difícil querer criar um padrão para isso porque é comum uma resposta demorar mais a medida que você está fisicamente longe do servidor. Também depende do seu objetivo. Um site, landing page, etc, é legal ter uma resposta curta para diminuir o tempo de carregamento de página. Mas quando for algo que precisa de recursos ou processamento, é normal demorar um pouco mais.

Answer (score -2):

O tempo de resposta de um endpoint é bom ou ruim dependendo de vários fatores:

- O que ele faz
- Quem (ou o quê) o acessa
- Em que ano estamos
- Quais as expectativas do consumidor
- Quanto se está disposto a pagar
- Quantas vezes será acessado por segundo / minuto
- Outras considerações

Se eu acessar um endpoint do DynamoDB e ele levar mais de 100ms, isso será ruim. Agora se eu acessar um endpoint que faz computações complicadas e ele levar alguns segundos, eu vou ficar feliz.

Se o meu endpoint é acessado 10 vezes por um cron que roda uma vez ao dia, provavelmente estou feliz com 1 segundo. Se ele é acessado em tempo real para montar uma página web, eu provavelmente vou querer que ele demore menos de 100ms. Se for para pegar preços de ações para fazer high-frequency trading, 1ms já é demorado demais.

Vinte anos atrás, um endpoint que demorava 1 segundo era considerado relativamente rápido. Hoje é considerado lento.

Eu dei o exemplo do DynamoDB lá atrás. O DynamoDB te dá uma latência de menos de 10ms em geral. Mas, se você pagar mais pelo DAX, você consegue uma latência de menos de 1ms.

Por fim, há a [lei de Little](https://www.objective.com.br/insights/lei-de-little/#:%7E:text=A%20f%C3%B3rmula%20da%20Lei%20de%20Little%20%C3%A9%20composta,temos%20a%20equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%3A%20L%20%3D%20A%20x%20W.): a latência do seu serviço define quantos consumidores ele consegue atender. Exemplo clássico do banco: se o atendente demora muito, a fila cresce. Ou seja, se você quiser atender 10 requisições por minuto, seu endpoint não pode levar mais de 6 segundos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).